# registration form validate username before press Register

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

my site running on php I like to add registration users form, with unique username.How make validation username before sending request to DB " Press Registration".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an similar scenario, I checked for existing user names when they click register, query the DB and compare with the name the user wants and if it already exists, alert the user and don't write the entry to your DB. A snippet is below along with a [GitHub link](https://github.com/jqguess/electronic) to the site where you can view the registration class yourself.

```
    // check if user or email address already exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email . "';";
    $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
    if ($query_check_user_name->num_rows == 1) {
        $this->errors[] = "Sorry, that username / email address is already taken.";
    } else {
    // write new user's data into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email)
    VALUES('" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_password_hash . "', '" . $user_email . "');";
    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
```

If you really need to check if the name is taken before hitting register, you could use an event listener such as "onblur", then make an Ajax call in the event function to handle the PHP.  Validating the name would look similar to the code above, just don't save the user yet, and take the appropriate action based on the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can you others even-listener instead of `onclick`.

You can use `onkeyup` , `onblur` and many more mouse based events to call the Ajax for checking your username existence in DB.

Answer (score 1):

> How make validation username before sending request to DB " Press
>   Registration".

Assuming that that you will validate if the `userName` is unique, you have to make a cal to `db`

But you can do this `onblur` event and use `ajax` for it

For example

```
<input type ="text" onblur="validate()">
```

**JS**

```
function validate(){
   // ajax code
}
```